# In Azure Devops, what is the easiest way to see the total story points for a particular sprint in a particular status

Tags: azure-devops, agile

In the board view, the top of the column shows a number of work items in each column.  I'd prefer that it instead show the sum of the story points of the work items in that column.  Barring that, I'm looking for the dead-simplest report/view/whatever that will show me the number of story points in each column of my grid.

Just switched from JIRA to Azure Devops and am feeling like this is a product that has too much complexity everywhere it isn't needed and not enough functionality for basic Agile usage.  Any tips for making the changeover more pleasant/getting JIRA-like behavior out of Azure Devops into the bargain would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Both are two different entities solving different purposes . Are you specifically talking about Azure boards?

Comment: @Robert Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HarishDhami As I understand it Microsoft's entire cloud offering is referred to as Azure Devops and includes boards, repos, tests, pipelines, and a ton of other stuff.  So, Yes, I'm referring to Azure Devops Boards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this issue , you can create a query that filters for User Story as the work item type and modify the column options to show Story Points and State.

[image]

Then, add a stacked bar chart that sums the Story Points.

[image]

For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-numeric?view=azure-devops#effort-or-story-point-queries-and-charts).

Comment: Thanks for this and sorry for the delay replying.  Happily your answer got auto-marked as best.  It doesn't actually solve my issue since my boards have multiple columns per state, and I want the totals per column, however I'm convinced at this point that azure can't do it.